# Filesnames with FUSE and IMAP

Tags: python, imap, fuse

I want to build a fuse-filesystem with IMAP4 in python. As filename I would like to use the subject of each mail. So I can rename the filenames and with this the Subjects.
But subjects can be used several times in one directory, so this breaks the common filesystem rules.
I wouldn't like to use a difficult directory-system (like [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=Filesystem_Suggestions#IMAPFS)) nor the unique Message-ID (then I cannot rename my files and directories).
I want to use e-mails in imap as (fuse-)directories and attachments of these mails as (fuse-)files. (For that only one layer of directories is possible.) The intention of this imapfs is to use mails as a storage-possibility.

Are there any suggestions how to deal with this filename problem? Thanks for any incitements.

Comment: +1 for concept, I'm also looking to be able to latch onto a Maildir store with FUSE to get a better grip on attachments.